# How set a response header when doing a GraphQL request with Apollo Client in Astro

Tags: apollo-client, request-headers, astrojs

I am using [Astro](https://docs.astro.build/en/getting-started/) and [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/introduction/#your-first-link-chain).

I need to set a custom Response Header.

How to set a custom response header when doing a GraphQL request?

In my Apollo Client file:

```
const myCustomHeaderLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    return forward(operation).map((result) => {
        res.headers.set('My-Custom-Header', 'my-value'); // How to get access to the `response` here?
        return result;
    });
  });


export const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  ssrMode: true,
  link: from([myCustomHeaderLink, httpLink]),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the client you `set` a request header and `get` a response header. Assuming you are trying to do the former then you'll want to use `setContext` in a custom link:

```
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

const myCustomHeaderLink = setContext(
  async (_, { headers: existingHeaders }) => {
    const headers = { 'x-my-header': 'myHeaderValue', ...existingHeaders };
    return { headers };
});
```

Then add this link to your link chain.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I think the only way to add the Response Header on server side is through [Astro Middleware](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/middleware/#_top).

Comment: Please make up your mind as to what you are trying to do. Set a response header on the server or set a request header on the client.